# Where is set the name that identifies the store in the redux extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-chrome-devtools, redux-toolkit

in case we have several stores, how can I set different names for those stores so when we click on the arrow selector we could easily identify which one we are picking?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The name is set by redux-devtools, You are looking for [name](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools/blob/main/extension/docs/API/Arguments.md#name) option.

> the instance name to be shown on the monitor page. Default value is `document.title`. If not specified and there's no document title, it will consist of `tabId` and `instanceId`.